# How to measure latency in paho-mqtt network

Tags: python, c++, mqtt, latency, paho

I'm trying measure the latency from my publisher to my subscriber in an MQTT network. I was hoping to use the on_message() function to measure how long this trip takes but its not clear to me whether this callback comes after the broker receives the message or after the subscriber receives it?

Also does anyone else have any other suggestion on how to measure latency across the network?

Comment: You mean, you want measure how much time it takes for the packet to reach subscriber from publisher?

Comment: yes I want to measure how long it takes for a packet to get from publisher to subscriber

Answer (score 3):

`on_message()` is called on the subscriber when the message reaches the subscriber.

One way to measure latency is to do a loop back publish in the same client e.g.

1. Setup a client
2. Subscribe to a given topic
3. Publish a message to the topic and record the current (high resolution) timestamp.
4. When `on_message()` is called record the time again

It is worth pointing out that this sort of test assumes that both publisher/subscriber will be on similar networks (e.g. not cellular vs gigabit fibre).

Also latency will be influenced by the load on the broker and the number of subscribers to a given topic.

The other option is to measure latency passively by monitoring the network assuming you can see all the traffic from one location as synchronising clocks across monitoring point is very difficult.

Answer (score 3):

I was involved in similar kind of work where I was supposed measure the latency in wireless sensor networks. There are different ways to measure the latencies.

**If the subscriber and client are synchronized.**

- Fill the payload with the time stamp value at the client and transmit
  this packet to subscriber.  At the subscriber again take the time
  stamp and take the difference between the time stamp at the
  subscriber and the timestamp value in the packet.
- This gives the time taken for the packet to reach subscriber from
  client.

**If the subscriber and client are not synchronized.**

In this case measurement of latency is little tricky. Assuming the network is symmetrical.

- Start the timer at client before sending the packet to subscriber.
  Configure subscriber to echo back the message to client. Stop the
  timer at the client take the difference in clock ticks. This time
  represents the round trip time you divide it by two to get one
  direction latency.

Comment: how do you get the subscriber and client to be synchronized?

Comment: if both subscriber and client have real time clock, you can configure the same date and time to same value. This is an easy method although not so accurate one but should be enough for your latency measurement.

Comment: NTP could be used for time sync as well no?

Comment: This answer gives a hint as to the complexities involved. We have more detail in our blog post https://gambitcomm.blogspot.com/2018/08/video-monitor-end-to-end-latency-of.html